# The Team Thanks The Following Sponsors or The Team Thank The Following Sponsors

Tags: grammar

As we are printing the words behind our t-shirt, my friend insisted that the correct word is thanks instead of thank.
Please advise

Comment: Your friend is correct. I honestly don't know why other than that it is obvious that one "thanks" is the commonly used and correct term, while "thank" sounds obviously wrong to my ear as a native English speaker.

Answer (score 0):

The word 'Team' is a collective noun and in this context is being referred to as a single unit; Therefore it is treated as singular -- in which case 'Thanks' is correct.

Were the individuals stressed, The team argued among themselves, it would be treated as plural.